# If $\mathbb E[X]=\infty $ and $\mathbb E[Y]=0$ and $X,Y$ independent, does $\mathbb E[XY]=0$?

Tags: probability

If $\mathbb E[X]=\infty $ and $\mathbb E[Y]=0$ and $X,Y$ independent, does $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]=0$ ?

Comment: Here is an example: Consider $X$ to be Cauchy and $Y$ taking values of $-1$ and $+1$ with prob. $1/2$ each. Then what will $E(XY)$ be?

Comment: @Math-fun $$\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[XY\mid Y=1]\mathbb P(Y=1)+\mathbb E[XY\mid Y=-1]\mathbb P(Y=-1)$$$$=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbb E[X\mid Y=1]-\mathbb E[X\mid Y=-1])=0 \ \ ?$$

Comment: But $E(XY|Y=1)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Math-fun Why ? Anyway, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]=0$ no ?

Comment: We need the moments of $X$ and $Y$ to exist for your result to hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\frac1{|Z|}$ where $Z$ has standard normal distribution. Then $\mathbb E[X]=\infty$. Let also $Y$ takes values $\pm 1$ with probabilities $1/2$ and does not depend on $Z$. Then $XY=\frac{1}{|Z|Y}$ and $|Z|Y$ has standard normal distribution. In this case the expectation of $XY$ does not exist, since $\mathbb E[|XY|]=\infty$.